# Is it possible to auto drop trigger and sequence when I drop table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-xe

I am using Oracle XE.
Is there any way to drop trigger and sequence automatically when I drop table?
Here is my table, sequence and trigger:

```
create table country(
country_id number(5) primary key,
country varchar2(36),
country_code varchar2(3)
);

create sequence country_seq
start with 1 increment by 1;

create or replace trigger country_trig
before insert on country
referencing new as new
for each row
begin
select country_seq.nextval into :new.country_id from dual;
end;
/
```

I am using this when main table record removes then all records of child table are auto deletes

Comment: A table's triggers are dropped when you drop the table. A standalone sequence created with `create sequence` is not associated with any table, but an internal sequence that is part of an identity column is dropped with the table, so it depends which you mean. I am not sure what your foreign key example has to do with the question though.

Comment: `an internal sequence that is part of an identity column is dropped with the table` How? when I drop table and recreate it and insert records then its getting values from sequence that was created previously

Comment: `create sequence country_seq
                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object` I mean not dropping sequence when table is dropped

Comment: Sequence `country_seq` has no connection with any table. How should Oracle know you want to drop it when you drop some table?

Answer (score 0):

Sequences created with `create sequence` are not associated with any particular table and so they are never automatically dropped. For one thing, you might reuse a sequence for multiple tables. There is no sense in which a sequence belongs to one table.

The only sequences that are automatically dropped are the ones generated as part of an [identity column](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1). (This feature was added in Oracle 12.1, and as you tagged 11g it means you don't have identity columns.)

Demo using identity columns (12.1 and later):

```
create table demo
( demo_id integer generated always as identity
, some_column varchar2(20) );

create or replace trigger demo_trg
before insert on demo for each row
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Trigger firing: '||$$plsql_unit);
end demo;
/
```

Now I have a table with a trigger, and also a sequence associated with the identity column:

```
select * from user_tab_identity_cols where table_name = 'DEMO';
```

| TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | GENERATION_TYPE | SEQUENCE_NAME | IDENTITY_OPTIONS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DEMO | DEMO_ID | ALWAYS | ISEQ$$_88798 | START WITH: 1, INCREMENT BY: 1, MAX_VALUE: 9999999999999999999999999999, MIN_VALUE: 1, CYCLE_FLAG: N, CACHE_SIZE: 20, ORDER_FLAG: N, SCALE_FLAG: N, EXTEND_FLAG: N, SESSION_FLAG: N, KEEP_VALUE: N |

Here, sequence `ISEQ$$_88798` was created automatically for my `demo_id` identity column. We can also see it in user_sequences:

```
select * from user_sequences where sequence_name = 'ISEQ$$_88798';
```

| SEQUENCE_NAME | MIN_VALUE | MAX_VALUE | INCREMENT_BY | CYCLE_FLAG | ORDER_FLAG | CACHE_SIZE | LAST_NUMBER | SCALE_FLAG | EXTEND_FLAG | SHARDED_FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ISEQ$$_88798 | 1 | 1E28 | 1 | N | N | 20 | 21 | N | N | N |

and in user_objects:

```
select o.object_name, o.object_type, o.created
from   user_objects o
where  o.object_name in ('DEMO','DEMO_TRG','ISEQ$$_88798');
```

| OBJECT_NAME | OBJECT_TYPE | CREATED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DEMO | TABLE | 27/02/2021 11:09:02 |
| DEMO_TRG | TRIGGER | 27/02/2021 11:10:42 |
| ISEQ$$_88798 | SEQUENCE | 27/02/2021 11:09:02 |

Now if I drop the table, all three disappear:

```
drop table demo purge;

select o.object_name, o.object_type, o.created
from   user_objects o
where  o.object_name in ('DEMO','DEMO_TRG','ISEQ$$_88798');

no rows selected
```

If I create a normal sequence as `create sequence myseq` then it has no association with the table, so if I want too drop it I must do it explicitly with `drop sequence myseq`.

Comment: I have updated my question and added my table, sequence and trigger.

Comment: Well, the short answer is that you have to drop any sequences yourself if you don't need them. Oracle can't just drop all database objects referred to in a trigger when you drop the trigger. What if the trigger referred to some other table, should it drop that too? What if you used the sequence in more than one trigger for more than one table?

Comment: `Well, the short answer is that you have to drop any sequences yourself`. Thanks for your efforts and favorable reply. Appreciated!!